# I can't display images in main.dart on vs code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

Whenever I upload an image in main.dart and I run the code I get the feedback that image could not be uploaded. What might be the problem

Comment: Did you add it to your assets in your pubspec.yaml? 
Please provide some code and show us what you already tried

Comment: Can you be please be more specific and provide some code snippet ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.